# Vue Router: How to redirect to root when user is reloading subpage

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In my vue application i want to redirect to the root of the website if the user is reloading one of the subpages (because there is some initialization work done). How could this be accomplished?

Here is my current routing setup:

```
const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: HeaderLayout,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: FacilitiesPage, name: 'facilities' },
      { path: '/dashboard/:facId', component: DashboardPage, name: 'dashboard' },
      { path: '/settings', component: SettingsPage, name: 'settings' },
      { path: '/remote-control/:facId', component: RemoteControlPage, name: 'remote-control' },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    component: PlainLayout,
    children: [{ path: '', component: LoginPage, name: 'login' }],
  },

  // Always leave this as last one,
  // but you can also remove it
  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)*',
    component: () => import('pages/ErrorNotFound.vue'),
  },
];
```

Comment: i hope your project will go well, you could also upvote my answer (the arrow up), i've upvoted yours, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very bad UX. Rather load your data for a root and child views on a page load. Otherwise your idea looks terrible... You are describing a design **WITHOUT** routing. So you don't need the router if you want this. Just don't use any URLs, load one page and process user clicks without navigation.

Routing is intended for preserving a navigation state, otherwise doesn't make sense.